# Output device for R that allows to manipulate variables with sliders (or other GUI elements)?

Tags: r, user-interface, plot, slider

I want to plot data and manipulate variables used in the plot (here: `rangeMin` and `rangeMax`). The consequences of variable change should be directly visible in the plot.

I'd like to have GUI elements (e.g. a slider) that I can use for changing the variable values of `rangeMin` and `rangeMax` and call the `rangePlot()` function.

Is there an output device in R, that provides GUI-Elements?

```
# generate example data
n <- 100
x <- 1:n
y <- x + (runif(n) * 25)

# rangeMin: value I'd like to manipulate using sliders
# rangeMax: value I'd like to manipulate using sliders
rangePlot <- function(x, y, rangeMin, rangeMax) {
  plot(x, y)

  # linear regression using datapoints a a certain range
  plotrange <- c(rangeMin:rangeMax)

  # linear model (y is mapped on x)
  linReg = lm(formula = y[plotrange] ~ x[plotrange])
  abline(linReg, col=2)

  # highlight points used for liniar regression
  points(x[plotrange], y[plotrange], col=2, pch=3)

  # show slope and intercept in the plot
  text(
    x=min(x),
    y=max(y),
    paste0(
      "intercept: ", linReg$coefficients[1],
      "\nslope: ", linReg$coefficients[2]
      ),
    adj=c(0, 1)
  )
}

# manual call
rangePlot(x=x, y=y, rangeMin=1,     rangeMax=n)
rangePlot(x=x, y=y, rangeMin=0.2*n, rangeMax=0.8*n)
rangePlot(x=x, y=y, rangeMin=50, rangeMax=60)
#
```

Comment: try either `shiny` or `manipulate` library both from RStudio

Comment: Also tkrplot, playwith, latticist and gWidgetsManipulate packages.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on the comments. The manipulate package for RStudio makes such things really easy. That package works within RStudio. If you want to use the same syntax without RStudio, there is an example in gWidgets2 (no need for gWidgetsManipulate):

```
require(tcltk); require(tkrplot)
require(gWidgets2)                      # require(devtools); install_github(c("gWidgets2", "gWidgets2tcltk"), "jverzani")
options(guiToolkit="tcltk")
source(system.file("examples", "manipulate.R", package="gWidgets2"))

w <- gwindow("Manipulate example", visible=FALSE)

manipulate({
  y <- get(distribution)(size)
  plot(density(y, bw=bandwidth/100, kernel=kernel))
  points(y, rep(0, size))
},
           ##
           distribution=picker("Normal"="rnorm", "Exponential"="rexp"),
           kernel=picker("gaussian", "epanechnikov", "rectangular",
             "triangular", "cosine"),
           size=picker(5, 50, 100, 200, 300),
           bandwidth=slider(0.05 * 100, 2.00 * 100, step=0.05 * 100, initial=1* 100), # integers needed
           button=button("Refresh"),

           container=w
           )
visible(w) <- TRUE
```

The GUIs look better with either the RGtk2  or Qt backends, but those are usually a bit harder to install.